# Why can't I open two files in two new windows from netrw in Vim?

Tags: vim

If I open Vim's file explorer to the current directory, I can open a file using the `o` key in a new window. I change focus between the opened file and the file listing using `CTRL-w w` key sequence. So far, so good.

However, if I change focus to the file explorer and open another file using the `o` key, this happens: a new window showing the file listing is created, and the window showing the previously opened file is focussed. I cannot switch to either of the file listing windows with `CTRL-w w` key sequence. Why does this happen?

How can I open a second file in a new window, and how can I move the cursor between the different windows?

Comment: Which Vim and netrw versions? Did you try the [latest available version](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW)?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat: 2:7.3.547-4ubuntu1.1 and netrw v145. I'll try upgrading because it looks like a bug or a configuration mistake.

Comment: Upgrading vim to 7.3 patches 1-816 and netrw to v146 solved this. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When encountering "strange" behavior like this, two things are important:

1. Try to minimize other influences; i.e. temporarily disable other plugins and irrelevant configuration in your `~/.vimrc`
2. It may be a bug; upgrade to the latest available versions of Vim (depending on your platform) and the plugin (the latest *netrw* version can be found [here](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW)).
3. If you can't possibly upgrade, at least locate and search the change log / issue tracker / mailing list; there may be hints about the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with a blank slate (* shows focus)…

```
+------------------------------+
| *                            |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
+------------------------------+
```

1. `:Ex` should replace the currently empty buffer with the netrw listing:

   ```
   +------------------------------+
   | * netrw                      |
   |                              |
   |                              |
   |                              |
   |                              |
   |                              |
   |                              |
   |                              |
   +------------------------------+
   ```
2. Hitting `o` should open the selected file in a new horizontally split window and give it focus:

   ```
   +------------------------------+
   | * file 1                     |
   |                              |
   |                              |
   |                              |
   +------------------------------+
   | netrw                        |
   |                              |
   |                              |
   +------------------------------+
   ```
3. The mapping for going back to the previous window (whatever and wherever it is) is `<C-w>p`. At this point, using this shortcut should give focus to the netrw listing:

   ```
   +------------------------------+
   | file 1                       |
   |                              |
   |                              |
   |                              |
   +------------------------------+
   | * netrw                      |
   |                              |
   |                              |
   +------------------------------+
   ```
4. Choosing a new file and hitting `o` should open it in a second horizontally split window (located right above the netrw window, between it and the window of the first file) and give it focus:

   ```
   +------------------------------+
   | file 1                       |
   |                              |
   +------------------------------+
   | * file 2                     |
   |                              |
   +------------------------------+
   | netrw                        |
   |                              |
   +------------------------------+
   ```
5. At this point, you can go back to the netrw listing with `<C-w>p` or cycle through your windows with `<C-w>w` (forward) or `<C-w>W` (backward) or use `<C-w>hjkl` or read `:h window-move-cursor`.

Comment: This is useful but doesn't solve my problem. At step 4, I get three windows, file1, netrw and netrw in that order. `<C-w>p` allows me to focus on the third window, but I can't focus on the second one with `<C-w>w`, `<C-w>W`, or `<C-w>p`.

Comment: This shouldn't happen if you hit `o` over a file. What you describe sounds like you've hit `o` over a directory. Do you use a plugin distribution or do you manage your config yourself? Could you show us your `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: I get this problem even when I delete ~/.vimrc and ~/.vim. Upgrading vim fixed it though.

Comment: Thanks Ingo. It's so easy to draw ASCII tables with Vim… it makes you want to use them everywhere!